# Is 'interface' a limited version of 'abstract' in Java?

Tags: java, oop

I'm in the process of learning C++ and have been trying to practice object oriented programming. A lot of references I'm using come in the form of Java tutorials.

One thing that I noticed is that there is this idea of 'abstract classes' and 'interfaces' in Java. I'm confused as to why exactly there would be two of these. It seems like everything you can do with an interface could have been performed identically with an abstract class.

So my question: does interface provide any additional features in Java? Or is it simply a way to designate that an abstract class should not allow inheriting classes to implement their own methods/data members?

Comment: Your class can implement **multiple** interfaces. So, interfaces provide multiple inheritance of **type**.

Comment: As said above, you can implement multiple interfaces. They are used to hold method signatures, constant fields, default methods, etc. The cool thing about default methods is that you can add implementation if needed right inside methods designated with the `default` keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java does not allow multiple inheritance. That means a single child class can't have more than one parent class. However, a class can "implement" multiple interfaces. This allows you to achieve multiple inheritance.

Before Java version 1.8, the major difference between an abstract class and an interface was that, you cannot define methods in an interface, but you can do that in an abstract class. But Java 8 allows implementation of "default" and "static" methods in interfaces itself.

And as to your question, if you inherit an abstract class then Java will force you to either implement the abstract methods of the parent class in the child class **OR** declare the child class as abstract itself. So if a child class inherits an abstract class, then the child class is free to declare and define it's own methods and data members. It can also override the methods of the parent abstract class.

The usage of interfaces and abstract class would depend on your needs. But in general it's better to use interfaces.

Comment: Terminology correction. Java does not allow multiple *extensions.
 Both extension and implementations are forms of inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Interface is a special kind of ABC. But why java distinguishes each other?
My understanding is that

- ABC focuses on common terms of classes
- Interface focuses on common features that instances have

I believe that's the reason that an object can inherit multiple interfaces but cannot have multiple super classes.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. In OOP abstraction is a main concept where you model real world things in a programming context with only considering the facts that are important to you. For example, if you create a Person class, what you really need is the person's name, birthday, address and some similar things. That's the basic idea of abstraction.

Why there are two ways of achieving abstraction is Java, Abstract Classes and Interfaces. In this case consider an example like, the **Bird** class. If you are said to show a bird, what you will actually show is a Parrot or any other bird of a specific type. Though we call them Birds in general, there's no exact thing called bird, other than the collection of different types of birds. in that case **Bird** is an abstract entity. That is, bird is too abstract to be shown in the real world.Therefore Bird is an abstract class.

When it comes to interfaces, suppose there's an interface called **iEat** which has the method **eat**. If we have classes Dog, Cat and Parrot implementing this interface, they all eat in general. But the way they eat is specific to the class. Therefore interfaces are used when you need a common behavior among classes, but the implementation depends on the class it is being implemented.

Also, there are several other differences like multiple interfaces can be implemented by a class and but only one abstract class can be extended by a class. But the main idea is that. Basically there are two ways like abstract classes and interfaces because for the design reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Literally, abstract class is a kind of class, and can be inherited. And abstract class can contain specific methods. But multiple inheritance is not allowed in Java, that is a class cannot inherit two classes or class.
However, interface is not class but appearance of class,and just describe how class acts, so y cannot instance an interface. But a class can implement several interfaces.

In short

- abstract class is abstract of whole class(attributes and behaviors), interface is abstract of partial class(only behaviors)
- relationship between abstract class and its subclass  is "is-a",and they are similar class. relationship between interface and its implement class is not specific relation.
- In design level.The design pattern of abstract is from bottom to top, that is, we must know subclasses before designing abstract class. But, we need not know any thing of class before designing interface.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing Interface means **adding capability** to your class.
Abstract class is unimplemented-**incomplete class**.

```
    //whoever extends this has to be some kind of Toy
    abstract class Toy
    {
        public void play(){
            //do some play
        }
    }

    //whoever implements this will be able to Fly
    interface Flyable
    {
        public void fly();
    }

    BirdToy extends Toy implements Flyable 
    {

    }

    Vehicle1Toy extends Toy
    {
        //like Truck
    }

    Vehicle2Toy extends Toy implements Flyable
    {
        //like helicopter
    }

    class Person implements Flyable
    {
      //like superman
    }
```